# multiple wmd textareas on the same page

Tags: markdown, wmd, wmd-editor

I'm trying to use the wmd markdown text editor for my site.  I have two textareas on my page and I need the wmd editor for both.  By default, it assigned it only to the first texarea, but how do I apply it to both textareas?

Also, I always get an extra new line at the end of my markedup text that was saved by wmd.  How can I prevent 
that?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670909/multiple-wmd-editors-so-forked-version-on-one-page

Comment: If you need to bump the question back to the front page, please try to do it in a way that improves the question, like providing more information, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[check my version.](http://moowmd.awardspace.info/moowmd-tutorial.html) It has multiple instances on the same page.