# Is there any WMD fork that handles multiple textareas

Tags: wmd

In addition to not being based on MooTools ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218443/multiple-wmd-textareas-on-the-same-page), [2](http://moowmd.awardspace.info/)), and having proper `ctrl-k` based code formatting support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, ended up going with the MooTools one.